# How to achieve CSS Position Absolute - Position Relative combination in WPF?

Tags: wpf, layout

I have a need to reproduce this CSS in WPF/XAML:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">Foo bar</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">Foo bar</div>
</div>
```

In essence, I need to have two elements positioned on top of each other within their container.

So far I have:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Foo bar">
    <TextBlock Margin="0,-16,0,0" Text="Foo bar">
</StackPanel>
```

The problem with above is that it does not scale. I don't want to hard code any margin figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place then on the same cell of a grid:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Foo bar">
    <TextBlock Text="Bar foo">
</Grid>
```

**Note:** Since there's no `RowDefinitions` or `ColumnDefinitions` specified, the grid have a default 1 row / 1 column. Since the elements don't have the property `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` set, they are placed on the 0,0 cell

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do non-pixel positioning, I usually put my items in a grid with rows or columns on the sides with a percentage or "star" value for padding.  That does scale.

So something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Height="80*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="FooBar" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Will render a textbox whose left edge is 10% from the left, no matter what the zoom.